# What is the parameter inside precision or recall in Evaluation class in WEKA java

Tags: java, weka

What is the parameter inside precision or recall while evaluating?
This is my arff file. IS_PRIVACY is the class attribute.It is written that parameter is
 "Parameters:classIndex the index of the class to consider as "positive" "
What should be then inside of eval.precision(?),should it be 0 or 1?
Is the index attribute index{0,1} or class index?

```
@attribute IS_PRIVACY {0,1}
@attribute reviewText string

@data
0,'Keeps crashing Since I upgraded android game crashing '
0,'Addictive I fan game app earn coins unlock diffrent colored lights How 
coins play games happened tbat mini games kind game '
0,'Ad free port original open source game '
0,'love it good excercise work '  

Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(trainingSet);
eval.evaluateModel(cls, testingSet);
Random random=new Random();
eval.crossValidateModel(cls, testingSet, 10, random); 
eval.precision(1);
eval.recall(1);
eval.fMeasure(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods `eval.precision(claasIndex)` and `eval.recall(classIndex);` use the classIndex as parameters. You cannot use 0 or 1 (values of the attributte `IS_PRIVACY`) as parameters of those methods because not always a class attribute is numeric, you could have nominal attributes (string) as class attribute and obviously you couldn't use an string as parameter of `precision()` or `recall()`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. So eval.precision(0) is what should be,right? as IS_PRIVACY is my class attribute and it's index is 0.

Comment: Yes, in your case is 0 but normally the class attribute is set as the last attribute in arff files.

Comment: Yes i know,actually when i converted from CSV to arff it was automatically like this. Probably because in CSV file class column were before the attribute column.Though i guess it won't be a problem even if the class attribute is the first attribute. Thank you very much for the reply. :) :) :)